# SQLite vs SharedPreference или как лучше хранить игровые ресурсы в игре

Tags: android, sqlite, android-shared-preferences

Есть игра, в которой, к примеру 20 различных игровых ресурсов пользователя.
Количество их постоянно(раз в 1-5сек) меняется.

**Вопрос:** Как лучше всего их хранить и как часто сохранять ?

Мои предположения:

1. Каждый раз писать ресурсы в SharedPreference.
2. Каждый раз писать ресурсы в SQLite.
3. Хранить ресурсы в каком-нибудь синглтоне и в onPause сохранять их в
   SharedPreference/SQLite.

Но по первым двум пунктам, мне кажется, что запись будут медленна в SharedPreference/SQLite. (?)

У кого есть опыт в таком - прошу поделиться, как вообще лучше всего это организовать?

Comment: при записи/изменении 20 значений раз в секунду, вы незаметите изменений в работе программы. Можете использовать или то, или то. Все зависит от контекста дальнейшего использования. Если данные не участвуют в выборках из базы и не должны коллекционироваться, то логичнее использовать SharedPreference. а вот если вам надо вести какую-то статистику, то SQLite в помощь)

Comment: Измерь скорость и расскажи

Comment: олсо, если вы будете портировать куда-нибудь игру (а вдруг), то sqlite легче портируется, наверное или есть какие-то врапперы для sharedPreference?

Answer (score 3):

Shared preference все таки лучше использовать только для сохранения прогресса и настроек, потому что на самом деле shared preference это простой xml, при увеличении объема значительно упадет скорость, рекомендую использовать SQLite .